# How to create a live CD?

Tags: 14.04, live-cd, remastersys

I am new to Linux distributions, currently working on Ubuntu 14.04. How do you make a live CD from a live installation? Earlier there was "REMASTERSYS".

Comment: Remastersys works fine with Ubuntu 14.04. Check the answer I gave [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/564657/332740)

Comment: Remastersys works fine. but getting error in the end. so i tried Relinux and got the same [error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615827/relinux-error-remastersys-error)

Comment: I have always made copies of my installation WITHOUT personal files. It means, I install software I want to use, make some modifications to the system and make a copy.  Also - maybe - there's not enough space on the hard disk for the copy you try to make. –

Comment: Do it manually please. You will learn a lot about computers and linux, it is fun and not that difficult. Have a look here for a starter: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 1):

It seems remastersys is not well supported in latest distribution. I suggest you use [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback). It also has some extra nice features. I have been able to successfully create an iso with it and written it to a 4G memory stick. However it failed to write to a 16G memory stick. I had to use unetbootin for that. My suggestion is to use [systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) for creating an iso file and then unetbootin for writing to USB.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=uck), also found through `apt-get`, or `synaptic`, and then for added flexibility there is [UCK-flow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/files/?source=navbar)

There are a few *extra* dependencies you *might* have to install, but 'uck' and 'uck-flow' are python scripts to help unpack, modify, and repack ISO images.

Edit:  I just checked the .deb file for `uck-flow` it went catatonic on installation.  I could easily build it from the source.

Unpack the archive;

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

and then

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

the executable is located `/usr/local/bin/uck-flow`, but there is also a menu entry at `System Tools` (in mine;-)

Comment: [Ubuntu-builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder/+download) might be a kinder choice for scripts.

Comment: remastersys and relinux works fine, but getting this error [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615827/relinux-error-remastersys-error)