# Relinux error , Remastersys Error

Tags: relinux

I got this error  when i tried Relinux and Remastersys to create an iso of current installation.
" *The compressed filesystem is larger than the iso9660 specification allows for a single file. You must try to reduce the amount of data you are making and try again.* "
Solutions please

Comment: "You must try to reduce the amount of data you are making and try again." is not the solution?

Comment: how do i do that ????what is to be done to reduce the amount of data ??

Comment: Remove software would be the most logical answer?!

Comment: sudo apt-get clean and rm -rf ~/.cache (if you're backing up the user) should do the trick

Comment: @ Rinzwind remove which software ?

Answer (score 0):

relinux and remastersys create a bootable .iso from your current system, which means that a good portion of your filesystem is directly copied (and compressed) to the .iso file.

If your filesystem is larger than 4GB, it will bail, since 4GB is the largest file size that the ISO 9660 Level 2 specification allows.

Keep the size of your filesystem under 4GB, if at all possible (although, /home will *not* be included, so that can be as large as you want). Slightly more than that (say, 5GB) probably won't matter (depending on the type of data that exists on your filesystem), since it is compressed, but don't go much larger than that.